# How "Questions" in List<Questions> relate to "T" in List<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working on an application that deals with lists. I have two scripts; one that deals with a specific class; and the second one that deals with everything else in the application. It's a True and False game/app which I'm learning to make through an online tutorial.

The first script is a [System.Serializable] script that just contains a string and a bool. The string here being the question and the bool verifies the question. The main Game Controller script makes an array out of the class, it also contains a list of unanswered questions that will periodically be updated once the question has been asked.

The line of code I don't quite get is

```
private static List<Questions> UnansweredQuestions;
```

Where "Questions" is the class that contains the question and the bool.

What function exactly does the `<Questions>` serve. I know that the T in `List<T>` refers to the type of elements in the list; which usually are string or int. How is T as a class defined here? Given that the class Questions contains a string and a bool, does it mean that the list created is a dictionary?

Comment: I am not sure that I quite get what you mean, but a list can be a list of anything including custom classes (e.g. Questions). Now, list is simply a bag, in that bag you can have balls, coins, or even other smaller bags that contain in themselves other items.

Comment: @Ghasan Not to be confused with `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T>` (although they are similar)

Comment: @PCLuddite Thanks! I was referring to the concept of it, but nice to know there is some class with such a name :)

Answer (score 2):

No, `List<Question>` is not a dictionary. It's a `List` that contains `Question`s.

`List<T>` being generic means that it can accept any type. The compiler essentially takes the code from `List` and replaces all instances of `T` with `Question`, just as if it had been specifically written as a list for `Question` types.

At its core, [`List<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) stores elements in an array, as `private T[] _items`. This array is then resized whenever it runs out of space.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down

```
private static List<Questions> UnansweredQuestions;
```

The access modifier `private` means that `UnansweredQuestions` will only be visible within the scope of the class it is defined in.

The keyword `static` means that you don't need an instance of your class. The same `UnansweredQuestions` is visible to all instances of your class, and to other static properties / methods in the class.

> What function exactly does the serve. I know that the T in List refers to the type of elements in the list; which usually are string or int.

`List<T>` means a List of a type to be named later. When you write `List<Questions>` you name that type. You tell the compiler you want a list of Questions objects.

> Given that the class Questions contains a string and a bool, does it mean that the list created is a dictionary?

No, it is really a list. If you have at least one object in the list, you could do something like

```
Questions firstQuestion = UnansweredQuestions[0];
if (firstQuestion.Answered == false) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(firstQuestion.Text);
}
```

This assumes your boolean is called Answered and your question text is called Text.

Comment: I'm loving this site already :) still working on believing how helpful it actually is. Say hypothetically, if I had a constructor that defines a string and an int (based on two args) and populated the list with those, it would accept constructors as the elements of the list?

Comment: @BowieSalvatore If by "accept constructors" you mean something like this `UnanswerQuestions.Add(new Question("How are you?", 3));`, then yes.

Comment: Even if you didn't have a 2 argument constructor, you can use syntax like this: `UnansweredQuestions.Add(new Question() { Text = "How are you?", Answered = false });`

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Think of it as multiple T's. Similar to `Array<T>`. T can be any type: int, string, Question class, etc. For ex:

```
Question question1 = new Question(); // only 1 question

List<Question> questions = new List<Question>(2);
questions.Add(new Question());  // 1st question added
questions.Add(new Question());  // 2nd question added

// access the second question by:
Question secondQuestion = questions[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<T>` is an `object`, which is the base of everything, which is like this `List<System.Object>`. When you declare `List<string>` it creates a list, using the class `System.String`.

This code: `private static List<Questions> UnansweredQuestions;`, creates a list, using the `Question` class.

So this code:

```
private static List<Question> UnansweredQuestions = new List<Question>(10);
```

Creates a 10 long list, using the `Question` class. Which is like an `Array`:

```
private static Question[] UnansweredQuestions = new Question[10];
```

`List`'s and `Array`'s save space and time, so you don't have to use something like this:

```
private static Question UnansweredQuestion1 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion2 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion3 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion4 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion5 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion6 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion7 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion8 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion9 = new Question();
private static Question UnansweredQuestion10 = new Question();
```

Plus `List`'s and `Array`'s allow indexing, so you can get an item like this `MyListOrArray[4]`. Which will return the item at that index. Whereas in the example above where there are 10 variables, you would have to get the values of them individually, like this `UnansweredQuestion4`.